# handle dropdownlist selected index in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, drop-down-menu

i have a drop downlist. When Selected Index changes I wanted to handle it in javascript. So, as starting step , I tried to print the value of list item text in a textbox through javascript. But could not accomplish it successfully. Here is the dropdownlist:

```
       <asp:DropDownList Width="300px" ID="PlaceHoldersDropDownList" runat="server"
                AppendDataBoundItems="True" TabIndex="3" AutoPostBack="True" 
                OnSelectedIndexChanged = "PlaceHoldersDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged"  >
            <asp:ListItem Value="">Select</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="ContactName">[Contact Name]</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="ProductName">[Product Name]</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="ProductShortName">[Product Short Name]</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="CurrentTime">[Current Time]</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="EventStartTime">[Event Start Time]</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="EventStopTime">[Event Stop Time]</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:TextBox ID="tb" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Here is the C# code

```
            protected void PlaceHoldersDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
                                                            EventArgs e)
    {
        var text = PlaceHoldersDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text;

        string x = text;
        PlaceHoldersDropDownList.Attributes.Add("onchange", "javscript:PasteTextInEditor
                                                                        ('"+text+"')");

    }
```

Here is the javascript

```
       function PasteTextInEditor(text) {

        var x = document.getElementById("<%= tb.ClientID %>");
        x.value = text;                    }
```

Can you please let me know the mistake I've been doing?

Comment: What happens if you simply `alert` the value?

Comment: the alert is not getting called. i think its not going into script

Answer (score 1):

first you have to set `AutoPostBack` to false to handle it in client side(javascript) and you don't need to add `onchange` event programatically, you can just write it in the `<asp:DrobDownList>` something like that

```
<asp:DropDownList Width="300px" ID="PlaceHoldersDropDownList" runat="server"
     AppendDataBoundItems="True" TabIndex="3" AutoPostBack="false"
     onchange="PasteTextInEditor()">
```

and the `PasteTextInEditor` method will become

```
function PasteTextInEditor() {
    var text = $("#<%= PlaceHoldersDropDownList.ClientID %> option:selected").text();
    $("#<%= tb.ClientID %>").val(text);
}
```

note I am using [jquery](http://www.jquery.com) syntax

Comment: The code lies in usercontrol. The error is coming from the parent page.

Comment: is this compilation error or runtime exception? I cannot get what causing this error without showing us the code, please provide more code to be able help you

Comment: i removed everything else and just kept the code but it still throws this error. I just have this entire code in usercontrol and i call this user control in another page

Comment: I created a sample code for what you want to do, you can download it [here](http://db.tt/f7SwkcjX) let me know if it doesn't help you

Answer (score 0):

Using [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) you can make the following:

1- turn off `AutoPostBack` and don't handle the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event:

```
<asp:DropDownList Width="300px" ID="PlaceHoldersDropDownList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" TabIndex="3" >
```

2- add a reference to jQuery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

3- add a "startup" script to hook the `onchanged` event for the dropdown list, read the javascripts comments for more details.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var ddl = $("#<%= PlaceHoldersDropDownList.ClientID %>");
        var txt = $("#<%= tb.ClientID %>");

        // hook the change event for the drop down list
        $(ddl).change(function (e) {
            var selectedValue = $(ddl).val();

            // set the selectedValue into the textBox
            $(txt).val(selectedValue);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hey. it doesn't work. I dont know jquery but how will script fire because i did not specify anything to run this script

Comment: It's fired when the document is ready, and the script binds a function to the onchanged event of the ddl. Then the function we passed by parameter to the `changed` method is executed when the onchange event is fired. Please download the working sample I wrote for you here: http://bit.ly/LyHbQ3

Comment: Thank you.. I'll look into it and try figuring out the problem